# How to get node parameter in Houdini with Python

Tags: python, houdini

I am very much new to Houdini and this might be something very obvious to ask but I have hit a brick wall. I would like to store a parameter, specifically the File Name of an alembic object so that I can validate the filename to see if it follows a namespace convention

[image: Property I am trying to get circled in red]

The following is all I have

```
import hou

node = hou.node('obj/alembic1/alembic1')
```

after getting the node, how would I get the File Name property? Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two main ways:

1 As you you've started to do in your code, access the node then access the parm HOM method of Node:

```
parm = hou.node('obj/alembic1/alembic1').parm('fileName')
```

2 Use hou.parm directly:

```
parm = hou.parm('obj/alembic1/alembic1/fileName')
```

parm is an object representing a parameter, to get the value of the parameter you need to call it's eval method:

```
parmval = parm.eval()
```

So something like this is the usual case:

```
node = hou.node('obj/alembic1/alembic1')
parmVal = node.parm('fileName').eval()
```

Note that parm.eval() will work for most cases, but sometimes you might need more verbose methods such as parm.evalAsNode().  Check out the help [here](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/hom/hou/Parm.html).

You can see the parm name to use in your code when you hover over the parameter name you want to access in the parameters window.  Ie if you hover over "File Name" in the Alembic node it will show:

> Parameter: fileName

Comment: parmVal = node.evalParm('fileName'). - This is another way.

Comment: It seems that you missed the leading "/" before "obj", which should be "/obj/alembic1/alembic1"